# How to explain using "from X import Y" to import a function Y which in uses a variable in the X file?

Tags: python, python-module

I know that the `reload()` function can't affect the `from <module> import <name>" which were used before the`reload()`, but I tested it and found something odd:

`test1.py`:

```
message="before editing"
def printer():
    print("reload",message)
```

`test1.py` (changed):

```
message="after editing"
def printer():
    print("reload",message)
```

then I used the interpreter and entered:

```
from test1 import printer
printer()
import test1
test1.printer()

#change the test1.py
reload(test1)
test1.printer()
printer()
```

after reload,the result is:

```
>>> test1.printer()
('reload:', 'after editing')
>>> printer()
('reload:', 'after editing')
```

So, why does `printer()` see the change? I thought the reason may be variable binding.

Comment: I want to know why printer() sees the change.I will edit the question again.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reloading *updates* the existing module. Functions from a module contain a reference to the module globals:

```
>>> printer.__globals__ is test1.__dict__
True
>>> 'message' in printer.__globals__
True
>>> printer.__globals__['message'] is test1.message
True
```

It is through this reference that globals like `message` are resolved. Because `reload()` function updates the *existing* module namespace, the `printer` function object will use the new value.

The problem with `reload()` and imported names from a module (rather than a reference to the module itself) is that those references are not updated. If you had changed the definition of the `printer()` function *itself* rather than the `message` global, then the imported reference to that function would not have changed.

Quoting from the [`reload()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload):

> When a module is reloaded, **its dictionary (containing the module’s global variables) is retained**. Redefinitions of names will override the old definitions, so this is generally not a problem.

*Emphasis mine*.

Comment: Is that reload can't affect the functions imported using "from** import",but the functions contains a reference to "sys.modules".After reload,the sys.modules changes,so the reference changes?

Comment: @ztelur: no, `sys.modules['test1']` *doesn't change*. The module object is updated in-place.